# ScrollView not flinging. Scrolling slowly

Tags: android, android-scrollview

I have the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/datatransfer_measure_list_layout_no_data"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/datatransfer_measure_list_textview_no_data"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="@string/measure_data_empty"
                android:textColor="@color/textcolorprimary"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:importantForAccessibility="no" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/datatransfer_measure_list_row_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:importantForAccessibility="no"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:textColor="@color/textcolorprimary" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/datatransfer_measure_list_button_send"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_button_ok"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/common_save"
            android:textColor="@drawable/custom_button_positive_text_color"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/datatransfer_measure_list_button_reset"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_button_cancel"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/common_cancel"
            android:textColor="@drawable/custom_button_negative_text_color"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I basically have three parts of this layout. First a layout containing just a textview to show if no data is set. It is getting invisible when there is data.

The second part is my recyclerview which is only showing up, when some data is set.

The last part are two buttons. My problem with this layout?
The scrolling is really slow. I dont mean lagging or something like that. I just can scroll a small part. It is not like my other scrollviews where i am able to fling the view so that it scrolls automatically. I have no idea what is different with this layout and why the scrollview works different here then in my other layouts. Is there something blocking the scrollview fling or something like that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your `Recyclerview` is colliding with `ScrollView` that's why scroll is not smooth.

Try disabling scrolling of recyclerview.

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.datatransfer_measure_list_row_parent);
recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)
```

Comment: That is it. Thank you!